# Windows Universal App maintain open WebSocket

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, windows-phone, win-universal-app

How to have a WebSocket open on Windows Universal App? Can I have my WebSocket to be open even when app is closed?

Comment: What would the WebSocket be open from on the client if no client is running to take/send a request.  Sorry but that seems pretty obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a Windows Universal app? Yes.
On a Windows Phone 8.1 app? No.

A Windows Store app can use a [ControlChannelTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger.aspx) to receive socket notifications in a background task even if the main app is suspended. This is demonstrated in the [ControlChannelTrigger StreamWebSocket sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-91f6bed8) in the Windows Dev Center.

ControlChannelTrigger is not supported in Windows Phone Store apps, but it is supported in Universal Windows 10 apps on mobile devices.

Comment: This doesn't work on Visual Studio (yet). Need to somehow add reference to `Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract.winmd` for `ControlChannelTrigger` class but Visual Studio keeps saying "reference could not be resolved".

Comment: It's not in the Universal API Contract so you'll need to add the reference (right click on the Project's References and choose Add Reference...) to either the "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP" or the "Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP". These are both in the Universal Windows/Extensions section of the Reference Manager window.